# Sylius 1.5: Change order status after successful payment

Tags: paypal, sylius, payum

I want to use paypal payment method in my sylius shop. I configured it as described in sylius documentation https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.5/cookbook/payments/paypal.html. After payment I am redirected back to the site with alert 'Payment is being processed.' https://gyazo.com/e654193a7d94df28f2704c5f9066820d and my orders remain with status 'Wating for payment' but the money from my paypal sandbox account is charged. How should I know whether my payment was successful and how should I change order status to 'Payed, Confirmed, etc'? I thought sylius does his by default but it seems not. I tried to apply event listener for the events  sylius.payment.pre_complete and sylius.payment.post_complete mentioned here https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.5/cookbook/payments/paypal.html but they are not triggered at all during payment process.

Here is my event listener configuration:
config/services.yaml:

`App\EventListener\OrderListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: sylius.payment.pre_complete, method: postCompletePayment }`